# How can I deploy AppBar Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

Im new in React Material UI and I am trying to deploy AppBar but i do not know how can I include childs into this NavBar. I want deploy AppBar when I click on the three left lines menu. My .jsx is:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/close';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';

const STYLES = {
title: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
},
titleStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center'
},
buttonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    color: 'white'
}
};

const rightButtons = (
<div>
    <FlatButton label="About" style={STYLES.buttonStyle} />
    <FlatButton label="Home" style={STYLES.buttonStyle} />
</div>
);

export default class MenuAlumno extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        abierto:false
    }
}

handleTouchTap = () => {
    //alert('Has clickado sobre el título');
    /*
    console.log(this.state.abierto)
    this.setState({
        abierto:true
    });
    */
    console.log(this.state.abierto)
    this.state.abierto = true;
    console.log(this.state.abierto)
}

render() {
    return (
        <AppBar
            title={<span style={STYLES.title}>- PLATAFORMA DE INCIDENCIAS -
</span>}
            onTitleTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap}
            titleStyle={STYLES.titleStyle}
            iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
            iconElementLeft={rightButtons}
        >
        </AppBar>
    );
}
}
```

But this code replaces the 3 left lines for FlatButtons. 
I want that when I click on the MenuButtonLeft a side menu deploy with the pages that contain my website (home, about us, contact,...). With the code I put before only shows the MenuButtonLeft and a Title into a Toolbar, but it does not do any action, it does not deploy any menu with the href to my others pages in my website.

Thank you.

Comment: can you please elaborate, what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: I want create a NavBar with childrens, not only the sidebar

Comment: Oh dear, this question has gotten into a right pickle! The title gave it away: it was two problems, one of which was `[solved]`, and the other one starts at `[edit]`! Unfortunately that's barely readable, and not the format we use here. If you have a new question (or multiple new questions, as per this case) then please add a new question. I have rolled it back to the last known good version of the first major question.

Comment: What are the two answers below an answer to? Are they to the first major question or the second one? I am wondering if it is better for you now to roll the edit forward again (to the second question) and to essentially delete the first question, whilst leaving enough context to make the whole thing at least somewhat useful for the new reader.

Comment: Needless to say, please don't do this again - it creates editing work for volunteers, and we already have a lot to do here as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem above! Here is the solution:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import NavigationMenu from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/menu';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/close';
/*
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/close';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
*/

const STYLES = {
title: {
    cursor: 'pointer'
},
titleStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center'
},
displayMenuTrue: {
    position: 'relative'
},
displayMenuFalse: { 
    display: 'none'
},
contentStyle: {
    transition: 'margin-left 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)',
    marginLeft: '0px',
    top: '0px'
},
contentStyleActive: {
    marginLeft: '256px',
    position: 'relative',
    top: '-144px'
}
};

export default class MenuAlumno extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        drawerOpen:false
    }
}

handleTouchTap = () => {
    //alert('Has clickado sobre el título');
    /*
    console.log(this.state.abierto)
    this.setState({
        abierto:true
    });
    */

    console.log(this.state.drawerOpen)
    this.state.drawerOpen = true;
    console.log(this.state.drawerOpen)

}

controlMenu = () => {
    if (this.state.drawerOpen) {
        console.log(this.state.drawerOpen)
        this.setState({ 
            drawerOpen: false 
        });

        $('.contenedor').css(STYLES.contentStyle);
    } else {
        console.log(this.state.drawerOpen)
        this.setState({ 
            drawerOpen: true 
        });


$('.contenedor').css(STYLES.contentStyle).css(STYLES.contentStyleActive);
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar
                title={<span style={STYLES.title}>- PLATAFORMA DE 
INCIDENCIAS -</span>}
                onTitleTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap}
                titleStyle={STYLES.titleStyle}
                iconElementLeft={this.state.drawerOpen ?  <IconButton>
<NavigationClose/></IconButton> : <IconButton><NavigationMenu/></IconButton>}
                onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.controlMenu}
            />
            <Drawer 
                open={this.state.drawerOpen}
                containerStyle={this.state.drawerOpen ? 
STYLES.displayMenuTrue : STYLES.displayMenuFalse}
            >
                <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
            </Drawer>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/close';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';

const STYLES = {
title: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
},
titleStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center'
},
buttonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    color: 'white'
}
};

const rightButtons = (
<div>
    <FlatButton label="About" style={STYLES.buttonStyle} />
    <FlatButton label="Home" style={STYLES.buttonStyle} />
</div>
);

export default class MenuAlumno extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        abierto:false
    }
}

handleTouchTap = () => {
    //alert('Has clickado sobre el título');
    /*
    console.log(this.state.abierto)
    this.setState({
        abierto:true
    });
    */
    console.log(this.state.abierto)
    this.state.abierto = true;
    console.log(this.state.abierto)
}

render() {
    return (
<div>
        <AppBar
            title={<span style={STYLES.title}>- PLATAFORMA DE INCIDENCIAS -
</span>}
            onTitleTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap}
            titleStyle={STYLES.titleStyle}
            iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"

        >
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer docked={false} width={200} open={this.state.abierto} >
        {rightButtons}
        </Drawer>
</div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: No, but AppBar does not deploy showing MenuItem in Drawer.

Comment: Instead of updating your question answer your own question